# date functionality

Tags: date, php

I want to print 7 days span for a particular date.. I have tried reading php manual and tried several things..nothing is working out.

```
<?php
function add_date($givendate,$day=0,$mth=0,$yr=0) {
      $cd = strtotime($givendate);
      $newdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(date('h',$cd),
                                            date('i',$cd), 
                                            date('s',$cd), 
                                            date('m',$cd)+$mth,
                                            date('d',$cd)+$day, 
                                            date('Y',$cd)+$yr));
      return $newdate;
}

?>
```

but this is not giving me any date.except today's date.

Comment: Have you tried using http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php ? It has some nice methods which ease the task...

Comment: Take a look at this. It may help you out. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: @DanArmstrong-not working..tried this one 1st..

Comment: @MihaiTodor-need to see this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DateTime class:

For example:

```
$today = new DateTime("now");

$yesterday = $today->modify('-1 day');
$yesterday = get_object_vars($yesterday);
echo $yesterday['date']."<br>";

$twoDaysAgo = $today->modify('-1 day');
$twoDaysAgo = get_object_vars($twoDaysAgo);
echo $twoDaysAgo['date'];
```

Comment: Beware that `$today->modify('-1 day')` modifies the actual object! So after this statement, @$today@ will not really be today anymore. If you want to prevent these side-effects, better make a clone first. E.g. `$yesterday = clone $today; $yesterday->modify('-1 day');`